# Java EE 6 Tutorial Component

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, crud

I am looking for a sample J2EE6 web service with a REST API and a database tier. My search took me to http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayk.html, which talks about obtaining  a list of J2EE6 examples by doing as follows:

To Update the Tutorial Through the Update Center

- Open the Services tab in NetBeans IDE and expand Servers.
- Right-click the GlassFish Server 3 instance and select View Update Center to display the Update Tool.
- Select Available Updates in the tree to display a list of updated packages.
- Look for updates to the Java EE 6 Tutorial (javaee-tutorial) package.
- If there is an updated version of the Tutorial, select Java EE 6 Tutorial (javaee-tutorial) and click Install.

The problem is the list has no `Java EE 6 Tutorial (javaee-tutorial) package` under `updates` or `Add-ons` or `Installed Components`.

I am using Netbeans 7.2, Glassfish 3.1.2, Mac OSX Lion. All I want is a J2EE6 web service with a Database tier and a REST API tier. Does anyone know of any such examples?

Answer (score 1):

Following is a link to Blaise's 5 part series about how to create restful web services. They do comply with the JEE6 specs.
http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-15.html

There might be many others, but I have used this before and did find it very useful.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will look into it and see if it works with JEE6.

Answer (score 0):

That document is for Windows and not very suitable to OSX.

Try this in OSX:

1. inside Glassfish Update Tool, push button "Edit Properties", then enable the publisher release.javaeesdk.oracle.com;
2. Click "Available Add-ons" in the left pane,and find in the right pane "Java EE Tutorial".